# Update scope half way through a scope method

Tags: angularjs, typescript

**EDIT:** I've put together a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18137/

I want the black to go up AND THEN the green to slide across... I do not know how to achieve this... Read on for more information:

---

*Side note: The code is in Typescript (re: () => {} )*

The following context shows a web page that has an overlaying div, and a couple of divs behind it. It also denotes the kind of animation that is occuring via a css class.

[image]

I have the following code (see references to diagram):

```
$scope.Resizing = true; // This prevents animations from happening (as a css class is linked up to it (see below))
$scope.MoveToPage( col, row ); // 2
$scope.$applyAsync(() => { // Update the view to remove the class and then start sliding up the overlay div
    $scope.FirstPageTop = -$scope.PageMap.WindowInfo.Height; // 3
    $scope.Resizing = false; // Re-enable animations // Finish
});
```

What it is supposed to do is:

- When Resizing is true, it removes a css class that animates stuff.
- It then runs the MoveToPage method that makes a position left equal a new number.. usually it would animate to the new position but in this instance i don't want it to (thus the Resizing attribute).

We can see the above expressed in my html:

```
<div class="column-wrap" 
            ng-class="{ 'column-wrap-animation' : !Resizing }" 
            ng-style="{ 'width': PageMap.ContainerWidth + 'px',
                        'left': PageMap.ColumnWrap.Left + 'px'}">
```

The procedure then applies the scope asynchronously (because if i use a simple apply, it throws an error) and as a callback to this method, I am then doing pulling an overlay off of the top of the page... and then setting Resizing back to false to re-apply animations.

**The problem:**

I need to slide off an overlay AFTER positioning the content underneath it. What is actually happening is, it slides the overlay off of the top, while the under page animates to where i've told it to go. How do i get around this css animation digestion problem...

Perhaps an even simpler question is, why might the class not be being removed when Resizing is set to false and actively i am telling it to update the scope?

**Explaining my context:**

Comment: I've ammended the jsfiddle to help you guys out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apparently use setTimeout to deal with the $scope.$apply issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18138/

```
$scope.Resizing = true;
$scope.MoveToPage( col, row );
setTimeout( function() {
    $scope.FirstPageTop = -$scope.PageMap.WindowInfo.Height;
    $scope.Resizing = false;
    $scope.$apply() // This is important
}, 1);
```

Comment: Use `$timeout`...it calls $apply internally...just remeber to inject it in controller or directive being used

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. Good idea.